# Why are duplicate keys printed when I'm looping through the hashmap?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, key-value

What is wrong with my code? I'm trying to print the keys but when I print the I'm getting duplicate keys. I was under the impression that when we add duplicate keys to hashmap, it replaces the previous key.

I'm trying to print all the repeating elements in the array.

```java
public static void repeatingElements(int a[], int n) {
  HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (map.containsKey(a[i])) {
      map.put(a[i], map.get(a[i]) + 1);
    } else {
      map.put(a[i],1);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {
      if (entry.getValue()>1) {
        System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- Input: `{12, 10, 9, 45, 2, 10, 10, 45}`
- Expected Output: `10 45`
- The output I'm getting: `10 10 10 45`

Comment: Is this the working or the non-working version of the code?

Comment: ( you can also use `System.out.println(map);` to see the content of the Map; even better, use a debugger to step trough the code and analyze what happens )

Comment: @user85421 apologies for the confusion. updated the code.
Also, when printing the map, I'm not getting duplicate keys, only the value associated with key is updated.

Comment: @Sören non-working code.

Comment: Move the entry set iteration outside of the loop that put values inside - currently you print the state of the map on every iteration of the loop putting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you are getting is a result of emiting the status of the Map on each iteration of the for loop.

Consider the state of the Map on each iteration:

```
12: [{12:1}]  Output: 
10: [{12:1}, {10:1}] Output: 
 9: [{12:1}, {10:1}, {9:1}] Output: 
45: [{12:1}, {10:1}, {9:1}, {45:1}] Output: 
 2: [{12:1}, {10:1}, {9:1}, {45:1}, {2:1}] Output: 
10: [{12:1}, {10:2}, {9:1}, {45:1}, {2:1}] Output: 10
10: [{12:1}, {10:3}, {9:1}, {45:1}, {2:1}] Output: 10
45: [{12:1}, {10:3}, {9:1}, {45:2}, {2:1}] Output: 10 45
```

So the total output ends up as: 10 10 10 45

Solution is to move that status output after the loop.

```
public static void repeatingElements(int a[], int n){
  HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(map.containsKey(a[i])){
      map.put(a[i], map.get(a[i]) + 1);
    } else {
      map.put(a[i],1);
    }
  }
  for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getValue()>1){
      System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it not the problem that you have your print loop at the wrong position?

```
public static void repeatingElements(int a[], int n){
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(map.containsKey(a[i])){
                map.put(a[i], map.get(a[i]) + 1);
            }
            else {
                map.put(a[i],1);
            }
        }
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getValue()>1){
                System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " ");
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- For all the values when first encountered, you put in a default value of 1.  Duplicate keys replace the current value.
- As each key is found, its value is replaced by the current value plus 1.
- So at the end of the first loop, your map looks like this because `10` occurs `3` times and `45` occurs `2` times.

```
2=1
9=1
10=3
12=1
45=2
```

Now if you move the last loop, outside the first, you will get  the following.

```
10 45
```

Here is the modified code.

```
public static void repeatingElements(int a[], int n) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (map.containsKey(a[i])) {
            map.put(a[i], map.get(a[i]) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(a[i], 1);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
            System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want to detect which items are duplicates and don't care how many times they occur, you can use sets.

- if the value, when adding it to the `seen` set is already there, it returns false, so add it to the `dups` set.
- since `sets` won't hold duplicates, continued adding an existing value won't make a difference.

```
public static void repeatingElements(int vals[]) {
     Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
     Set<Integer> dups = new HashSet<>();
     for(int val : vals) {
         if (!seen.add(val)) {
             dups.add(val);
         }
     }
     System.out.println(dups);
}
```

prints

```
[10, 45]
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I was under the impression that when we add duplicate keys to hashmap, it replaces the previous key. ..."*

Correct, it replaces the *key* with the same *"hash-code"*.
Here is the source code, from the *[OpenJDK](https://openjdk.org/)*.

*[GitHub – java/util/HashMap.java – putVal](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L631)*.

> *"Why are duplicate keys printed when I'm looping through the hashmap? ...
>
>
>
> ... I'm trying to print all the repeating elements in the array. ..."*

Print the values after the *loop*.

```java
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(map.containsKey(a[i])){
        map.put(a[i], map.get(a[i]) + 1);
    }
    else {
        map.put(a[i],1);
    }
}
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getValue()>1){
        System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " ");
    }
}
```

And, for reference, you can use the *[Map#compute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction))* method.

```java
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    map.compute(a[i], (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : ++v);
```

Or, the *[Map#merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction))* and *[Integer#sum](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#sum(int,int))* methods.

```java
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    map.merge(a[i], 1, Integer::sum);
```

Another approach is to use the *[Collections#frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,java.lang.Object))* method, and a *[Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)*.

```java
void repeatingElements(int a[]){
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(a).boxed().toList();
    new HashSet<>(list).forEach(
        x -> {
            if (Collections.frequency(list, x) > 1)
                System.out.print(x + " ");
        });
}
```

Comment: I presume you realize that for each `Collections.frequency` call it iterates over the entire list for each value in the set.